# Why are planetary probe RTGs tilted at a jaunty angle?

Tags: design, probe, rtg, dragonfly

This image from here: [Does the Dragonfly project (quadcopters on Titan) envision attached RTG's or would they be static and revisited for charging?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34344/does-the-dragonfly-project-quadcopters-on-titan-envision-attached-rtgs-or-wou)

[image]

and this image

[image]

show that the RTGs on these two recent missions are tilted at a stylish angle relative to the main body of the vehicle.

Why is that? There's a (to put it nicely) speculative thread on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/curiosityrover/comments/1d2z78/why_is_curiositys_rtg_on_an_angle_to_the_rest_of/) but the only guess that seems vaguely plausible is the one about packaging volume in the aeroshell.

Comment: Seems like just keeping the body out of "line of fire" of heat radiating off the radiator blades.

Comment: Wouldn't having the RTG axis parallel to the main body axis be even better for that?

Comment: Looking at the the first image, which includes the outline of the hatch used to insert the RTG just before launch: if the RTG were horizontal, there would have to be a hatch _in the heat shield_. So I think the top comment in that Reddit thread nails it. Now to find references...

Comment: having the axis run through the centre of volume of the vehicle is the best way of radiating away from the vehicle

Comment: @JCRM looks like neither vehicle has that.

Comment: It's a [standard configuration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/205840/51174).

Comment: @uhoh I thought those things were powered by Soylent Green or somesuch.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the matrix was overall, but individual robots must have had self-contained power sources of some kind.

Comment: @uhoh https://i.imgflip.com/2u96vy.jpg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Dragonfly cruise stage looks rather similar to Curiosity's cruise stage, so I've looked at Curiosity. Curiosity's backshell contains a hatch. This was [used to install the RTG](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2011/3217.html) at the last possible moment (a few days before launch, long after the rover had been packaged in its backshell plus heat shield.

Here is Curiosity's backshell being prepared for encapsulating the rover. You can see the hatch.

[image]

> The MMRTG won't be installed until just a couple of days before the launch, because it throws off so much heat. Once the rover has launched, a cooling system will vent the excess heat to space, but between now and then it takes a pretty powerful cooling system to keep the MMRTG from heating up the interior of the spacecraft to hazardous levels. I was told a while ago that they have three redundant cooling systems working to keep the spacecraft at a safe temperature between MMRTG installation and launch.

For Curiosity, this means the RTG must be installed so it's accessible from the backshell. If it were installed horizontally, the hatch would have to go through the heat shield, and that's something spacecraft designers try to avoid as much as possible.

In the drawing you can see Dragonfly has the same packaging issue: if the RTG were horizontal, the hatch would have to go through the heat shield.

Comment: there's a nice image here as well https://phys.org/news/2019-03-nasa-mars-rover.html