# What is the equivalent of Curiosity's "MSL" in the context of Perseverance? What's the official name of the mission? Are the distinctions similar?

Tags: nasa, terminology, curiosity, perseverance, mars-science-laboratory

Answers to [Where does MSL end and Curiosity begin?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26500/12102) explain the difference. There was much fanfare for the naming contest for the Perseverance rover, but I don't know what the mission is called.

**Question:** What is the equivalent of Curiosity's "MSL" in the context of Perseverance? What's the official name of the mission? Are the distinctions similar? Will it also be a "science laboratory" while in transit to Mars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [my extensive research on the topic](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=Perseverance%20mars%20mission%20wikipedia&s=d), [Mars 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2020) is the name of the mission; Mars 2020 is to MSL as Perseverance is to Curiosity, but the Mars 2020 mission also includes the [Ingenuity drone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Helicopter_Ingenuity), which had no parallel in MSL. I don't see any references to a "science laboratory" on the Mars 2020 page.

Comment: Thanks! I'd always thought that the term "science laboratory" meant that there was stuff that was "doing science" besides the rover, but I don't see anything about that in the [linked question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26500/12102) so I've asked separately: [Did the Mars Science Laboratory do any science that wasn't done by Curiosity proper?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45528/12102)

Comment: Oh, I just caught that, grin!